# Oracle - TRIGGER that UPDATES another TABLE - " statement ignored "

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

Hello I am writing a Trigger that Updates SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO whenever it is changed in table SCOTT.DEPT.DEPTNO. However I have got underlined `UPDATE SCOT.EMP` - "statement ignored". Could anyone throw light on a possible solution or root of the problem please?

The Trigger compiles, but when I look inside the trigger the statement is underlined.

```
create or replace TRIGGER Trigger1
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF DEPTNO ON SCOTT.DEPT  
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF(:NEW.DEPTNO != :OLD.DEPTNO)
     THEN
        UPDATE SCOTT.EMP               ----- statement ignored
        SET DEPTNO = :NEW.DEPTNO
        WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = :OLD.DEPTNO;  
     END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It's `SCOT`, should be `SCOTT`.

Comment: Yea I see. Fixed that, the problem is still statement ignored. This line fixed my problem  only to create trigger ````ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = SCOTT;```` But the problem still exists, Its in SCOTT schema, and all of the tables aswell

Comment: `where scott.emp.deptno = ...` is unnecessary, it throws `ora-0904` for me, just use `where emp.deptno = ...` or `where deptno = ...` Aliases for columns are needed when you work with object types. Here you work on one schema, simple types, everything belongs to SCOTT.

Comment: Good to know thanks, I have changed it but the statement ````UPDATE SCOTT.EMP```` is still underlined, no matter if i change it to EMP or not.

Comment: I made a little [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=60486cbc2c726f5500c29bf5c2693550) and this trigger works. I changed somewhat, because when you insert new department it has nothing to update in emp and when you delete null is compared to deptno, which won't work. You should add `if updating` and `if deleting` clauses, but it's logic and does not explain any errors you have, at least I do not see any.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird, so the answer was to DROP all of the triggers, because I have made 2 triggers in 2 schemas ( System, and SCOTT ) I have dropped them, then created 1 in SCOTT and it's working.

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = SCOTT;

create or replace TRIGGER Trigger1
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF DEPTNO ON SCOTT.DEPT 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF(:NEW.DEPTNO != :OLD.DEPTNO)
     THEN
        UPDATE SCOTT.EMP 
        SET DEPTNO = :NEW.DEPTNO
        WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = :OLD.DEPTNO;  -- lub NEW w innym przypadku
     END IF;
END;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE DEPT SET DEPTNO = 69 WHERE DNAME = 'SALES'; 
select * from dept
select * from emp
rollback;
```

Comment: Glad you found answer. Powodzenia ;-)

Comment: Thank you ... :)